Need help to understand subtle difference using Replace in Association
Consider these two rules, which I initially considered as equivalent. Now I use rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationA as a "bug fix" in my code and use it instead of my "buggy" rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB. Unfortunately I still struggle to understand why they yields different answers. I don't think it is a Mathematica bug, simply want to understand what's going on here.
rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB = {HoldPattern[
     Times[mult_, arg2_Plus]] :> (((Times[mult, #1] &) /@ arg2))};

rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationA = {HoldPattern[
     Times[mult_, arg2_Plus]] :> Distribute[Times[mult, arg2]]};

Now apply both rules inside Association for this input
testSimple = <|
   "mykey" -> ((5 + a[1] - a[2] - a[3])/
        32 + (-43 + 3*a[1] + a[2] - a[3])/
        32 + (-5 + a[1] - a[2] + a[3])/
        32 + (43 + 3*a[1] + a[2] + a[3])/32)/4|>;

{Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationA, All], 
 Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB, All]}

(*{<|"mykey" -> a[1]/16|>, <|"mykey" -> a[1]/64|>} *)
The behavior seems is related to a Replace[,All], which tries to make substitution at deepest level first (I need this), since everything works well with ReplaceAll[]. May be somebody can explain this subtlety?

I know you didn't ask about this, but are you actually wanting something like Expand rather than the Distribute or the mapping approach?

@lericr Expand in principle can be used as well. In short the real problem is that I define some structure that is convenient to input, but takes long time to expand. Then I convert the structure to Association representation (which is not convenient to input), but is much faster to expand. In the above example the structure under conversion was removed.

@DanielLichtblau  When you will have some spare time You may be want to look at this example. From my point of view this is a really interesting case of unexpected behavior, though it did't attract attention and even has one answer which is completely unrelated to the problem.

The problem is that Map doesn't care about arithmetic rules. Consider this:
fun /@ (2  x) // FullForm
(* fun[2]*fun[x] *)

So, let's replace fun with something arithmetic:
#/z & /@ (2  x)
(* (2*x)/z^2 *)

Okay, so what? Well, in the course of evaluating the result you get after applying rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB, you end up evaluating an expression just like I showed above. This only happens under very specific conditions, and you coincidentally stumbled on that. Here's a simplified example:
testSimple = <|"mykey" -> ((a + x)/y + (-a + x)/y)/z|>;
resultB = Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB, All];

Now let's trace through how resultB would get evaluated after that (if we just extract it from the association, it'll evaluate):
Trace[Values@resultB]

I'm not going to paste the whole result here, but if you scan through it you'll notice that at some point, because of cancelling and simplifying, we'll hit this expression:
(#1/z & ) /@ ((2*x)/y)

If we didn't have just the right cancellation and simplification, we wouldn't be trying to map that function on a monomial, and everything would seem fine. But in this case, we end up doing the 1/z operation three times instead of just once. So, the final result is
{(2*x)/(y*z^3)}

instead of
{(2*x)/(y*z)}

which we would have gotten with the Distribute approach.

That indeed gives an explanation I am satisfied with.  So, my precaution with arg2_Plus was not sufficient do to cancelation. This behavior, however, probably never can happen if we start to apply rules from level 0 and then going deeper, i.e. with ReplaceAll[] or ReplaceRepeaded  (or can?). To summarize Replace[, All] can surprise you (in fact I used the buggy rule many years and the results always were correct ... until now)  By the way, the above example, was extracted from output which had few millions leaf count.

Association has the attribute "HoldAll". Therefore, if you want to evaluate the replacement, you need "Evaluate" like:
rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB = {HoldPattern[
     Times[mult_, arg2_Plus]] :> 
    Evaluate[(((Times[mult, #1] &) /@ arg2))]};

rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationA = {HoldPattern[
     Times[mult_, arg2_Plus]] :> 
    Evaluate[Distribute[Times[mult, arg2]]]};

With this:
Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationA, All]


And, although I doubt that you want to use "Distribute":
Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB, All]



That don't explain the behavior as the following experiment shows:Attributes[Association]
Unprotect[Association]
ClearAttributes[Association, HoldAllComplete]
Attributes[Association]   {Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationA, All],
Replace[testSimple, rulesPlusMultScalarAssociationB, All]};
Normal[%] // Expand . Results differ.
